# Condition in Jenkins pipeline on the triggers directive

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Jenkins has a nice relatively comprehensive [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#flow-control) about Jenkinsfile syntax. But I still not find there an answer is it possible to do a flow control on the top level of pipeline? Literally include something `if` just in `pipeline {}` section (Declarative) like:

```
pipeline {
    if (bla == foo) {
        triggers {
            ...configuration
        }
}
```

or

```
pipeline {
    triggers {
        if (bla == foo) {
            something...
        }
    }
}
```

`triggers` section is a section which can be included only once and only in the `pipeline` section. But `if` statement has to be applied only in stage level seems.

Do anyone know how to conditionally include something in direcitves, such as, `triggers`, or conditionally include directives itself?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't use flow control in a pipeline outside of `when` and `script`, but you can call functions for things like trigger parameters:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers{ cron( getCronParams() ) }
    ...
}

def getCronParams() {
    if( someCondition ) {
        return 'H */4 * * 1-5'
    }
    else {
        return 'H/30 */2 * * *'
    } 
}
```

Another way is to generate your pipeline script dynamically using `evaluate()`:

```groovy
evaluate """
pipeline {
    agent any        
    ${getTriggers()}    
    ...
}
"""

String getTriggers() {
    if( someCondition ) {
        return "triggers{ cron('H */4 * * 1-5') }"
    }
    else {
        return "triggers{ pollSCM('H */4 * * 1-5') }"
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I do have a configuration as below, is there a way to enable based on a condition? if condition is false, I don't want to add any triggers. `triggers {
            gerrit dynamicTriggerConfiguration: 'true',
                triggerConfigURL: Url,
                serverName: 'review-gerrit',
                triggerOnEvents: [
                    commentAdded(commentAddedTriggerApprovalValue: '1', verdictCategory: 'Code-Review')
                ]
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by zett42's answer, I created a conditional trigger with Gerrit trigger plugin. The trigger is disabled when the "isGerrit" variable is set to false. It seems that as of today, Jenkins doesn't allow "if" directives to surround the "trigger" declaration, so you have to tinker with its parameters in order to make it not work for specific cases.

```
triggers {
  gerrit customUrl: GERRIT_HOST,
  gerritProjects: !isGerrit ? [] : [[
    branches: [
      [compareType: 'PLAIN', pattern: 'master'],
      [compareType: 'PLAIN', pattern: 'database']
    ],
    compareType: 'PLAIN',
    disableStrictForbiddenFileVerification: false,
    pattern: 'myProject'
  ]],
  serverName: 'gerrit',
  triggerOnEvents: [patchsetCreated()]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of issue: `cron()` were triggered on tags, PRs and branches while I wanted to limit it to daily run on main branch.

Using `properties`, I was able to parameterize the triggers:

```
// triggers
def job_triggers = []
if(env.BRANCH_NAME == "master" || env.BRANCH_NAME == "main") {
   job_triggers << cron('H 2 * * 1-5')
}
properties([pipelineTriggers(job_triggers)])
```